# Inner class for listener in Java, is this bad practice?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

Is this the right way of doing this?
Iam using the MVC pattern.

in my View class, i have a`Button`.

```
Button fooButton = new Button();

public void addFooButtonListener(ActionListener foo){
    fooButton.addActionListener(foo);
}
```

In my Controller class constructor:

```
 this.theView.addFooButtonListener(new Listener());
```

In the Controller Class I use a inner Class named `Listener`

```
class Listener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //do whatever i want
    }
}
```

I have been told, that this is not the right way of doing this?
is this true? If yes, what is the right way?

Comment: Thats perfectly fine, but you could also have created anonymous class implementation of ActionListener like __new ActionListener(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){// To Do your task here }}__

Comment: Or if you are working Java 8 or above, you could have used lamda expression as well

Comment: @AmanChhabra How to i use lambda in a mvc pattern?

Comment: If you use that `Listener` only once, then an anonymous class like suggested by @AmanChhabra should suffice. If the `Listener` implementation is used multiple times though, then your current approach is perfectly fine

Comment: I don't think it's a bad practice. Maybe, if code grows in size, or you have more Listener classes for different buttons or whatever, you should extract Listener to another class. But your code it's perfectly fine

Comment: @AmanChhabra And one more question.. if i have multiple Buttons, should i create multiple inner classes in constructor?

Comment: To me it's perfectly fine to have an inner class, as long that the class is not too long. If the inner class is too long I prefer to extract it. If it is just a single line of code and it is under Java 8 I prefer lambdas. Even for more than one inner class. Just mantain code clean.

Comment: @ErwinIvanov I tried to explain all your doubts in my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shared, your current code is **perfectly fine** and there is no issue in it. However, you could have used below implementations :

**Anonymous Class:**

```
new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // To Do :: Task here
    }
}
```

**Lambda Expressions:**

```
button.addActionListener(e -> {
    // Task implementation here
});
```

Though it depends upon requirement, but the only disadvantage I can see in your implementation is the case when you have multiple button with different actions, which will end up in large amount of inner classes.

Also, if you feel that the same action can be used in different class,  you can also make a separate class implementing `ActionListener` in maybe `listeners` package and then use it among all classes.

Again, that all is requirement specific and accordingly you can choose whatever suits you the best in your project.

Comment: What should i consider using when having more than one Button, with different actions?

Comment: If you are using Java 8 and you think that all actions are button specific then I would suggest go for lambda expressions

Comment: And how should i do the lambda expression in my controller class?

Comment: I have already shared that my in answer, the second option __button.addActionListener(e -> {
    // Task implementation here
});__

Comment: You have to update this statement: __this.theView.addFooButtonListener(new Listener());__